# @font-face on chrome PC jagged alias

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have seen a handful of posts regarding fixes from PC `chrome` browser and jagged `@font-face` outputs but none have been able to fix my sample http://bit.ly/XyYtRX 
Everything seems to look good except for chrome (first time where IE is not the issue!)

here is my attempt

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_BreeBold';
    src: url('fonts/BreeBold.eot');
    src: local('Conv_BreeBold'), 
    url('fonts/BreeBold.svg') format('svg'), 
    url('fonts/BreeBold.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fonts/BreeBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.demo {
    font-family:'Conv_BreeBold',Sans-Serif;
    width:800px;
    margin:10px auto;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid #666;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:36px;

text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg); 
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

any suggestion please, thank you.

Comment: Have you read up on the current issue in chrome and that `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` does nothing? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141425

Comment: @HenrikAmmer i've realised it does nothing from trying.  looking for a fix